# Three Dependent Dropdowns Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-5

I have a form country, state and area that looks like the following:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('country') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="inputCountry" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Country*</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
                    <option value="">Select a country</option>
                    @foreach ($countries as $country)
                        <option value="{{ $country->id }}">{{ $country->country }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('state') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="state" class="col-lg-2 control-label">State*</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state">
                </select>
            </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('area') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Area*</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="area" id="area">
                </select>
            </div>
</div>
```

I have a script that allows showing what kind of state (i.e. second dropdown) that is depending on the country selection (first dropdown). I have no problem with the first and second dropdown.

However, the problem comes when I want to include the third dropdown for the area that depends on what country and state is selected.
This is the script I have for the area. The country_id and state_id are getting the same value which is apparently incorrect.

```
<script>
$('#state').on('change', function(e) {
        console.log(e);

        var country_id = e.target.value;              <---- not sure what I should change for this.
        var state_id = e.target.value;

        //ajax

        $.get("/page/ajax?country_id="+country_id+"&state_id="+state_id, function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $('#area').empty();
            $('#area').append('<option>Select an area</option>');
            $.each(data, function(index, areaObj) {

                $('#area').append('<option value="'+areaObj.id +'">'+ areaObj.name +'</option>');
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

After spending some times on Google,
I got the correct value for the `country_id` by changing the the following:

`var country_id = e.target.value;` to `var country_id = $('select[name="country"]').val();`

The area selection is not listing any data but this `<option>Select an area</option>`.

I got the following details from the Chrome's inspect->preview:

```
Collection {#261
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => Area {#260
      #fillable: array:3 [
        0 => "area"
        1 => "state_id"
        2 => "country_id"
      ]
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:2 [
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "Corvallis"
      ]
      #original: array:2 [
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "Corvallis"
      ]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => Area {#270
      #fillable: array:3 [
        0 => "area"
        1 => "state_id"
        2 => "country_id"
      ]
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:2 [
        "id" => 7
        "name" => "Portland"
      ]
      #original: array:2 [
        "id" => 7
        "name" => "Portland"
      ]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

and Chrome's inspect->response:

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if ('sf-dump-compact' == oldClass) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if ('sf-dump-expanded' == oldClass) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = newClass; if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (a[s].className !== newClass) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; return function (root) { root = doc.getElementById(root); function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a) { if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if ('sf-dump-compact' == r.className) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } }); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); root = t; len = t.length; i = t = 0; while (i < len) { elt = root[i]; if ("SAMP" == elt.tagName) { elt.className = "sf-dump-expanded"; a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '<span>&#9660;</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { toggle(a); } } else if ("sf-dump-ref" == elt.className && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { t = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); t.parentNode.insertBefore(a, t); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>&#9654;</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>&#9654;</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '&hellip;'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } ++i; } }; })(document); </script> <style> pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre; padding: 5px; } pre.sf-dump span { display: inline; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact { display: none; } pre.sf-dump abbr { text-decoration: none; border: none; cursor: help; } pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border: 0; outline: none; }pre.sf-dump{background-color:#fff; color:#222; line-height:1.2em; font-weight:normal; font:12px Monaco, Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; position:relative; z-index:100000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-cchr{color:#222}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref{color:#a0a0a0}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta{color:#b729d9}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index{color:#a71d5d}</style><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-981673028 data-indent-pad="  "><abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection" class=sf-dump-note>Collection</abbr> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#261</a><samp>
  #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">items</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:2</span> [<samp>
    <span class=sf-dump-index>0</span> => <abbr title="App\Models\Area" class=sf-dump-note>Area</abbr> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#260</a><samp>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">fillable</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:3</span> [<samp>
        <span class=sf-dump-index>0</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">area</span>"
        <span class=sf-dump-index>1</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="8 characters">state_id</span>"
        <span class=sf-dump-index>2</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="10 characters">country_id</span>"
      </samp>]
      +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">timestamps</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>false</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">connection</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">table</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">primaryKey</span>: "<span class=sf-dump-str title="2 characters">id</span>"
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">perPage</span>: <span class=sf-dump-num>15</span>
      +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">incrementing</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>true</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">attributes</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:2</span> [<samp>
        "<span class=sf-dump-key>id</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>3</span>
        "<span class=sf-dump-key>name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="9 characters">Corvallis</span>"
      </samp>]
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">original</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:2</span> [<samp>
        "<span class=sf-dump-key>id</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>3</span>
        "<span class=sf-dump-key>name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="9 characters">Corvallis</span>"
      </samp>]
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">relations</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">hidden</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">visible</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">appends</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">guarded</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:1</span> [<samp>
        <span class=sf-dump-index>0</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str>*</span>"
      </samp>]
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">dates</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">dateFormat</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">casts</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">touches</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">observables</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">with</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">morphClass</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">exists</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>true</span>
      +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">wasRecentlyCreated</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>false</span>
    </samp>}
    <span class=sf-dump-index>1</span> => <abbr title="App\Models\Area" class=sf-dump-note>Area</abbr> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#270</a><samp>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">fillable</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:3</span> [<samp>
        <span class=sf-dump-index>0</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">area</span>"
        <span class=sf-dump-index>1</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="8 characters">state_id</span>"
        <span class=sf-dump-index>2</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="10 characters">country_id</span>"
      </samp>]
      +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">timestamps</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>false</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">connection</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">table</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">primaryKey</span>: "<span class=sf-dump-str title="2 characters">id</span>"
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">perPage</span>: <span class=sf-dump-num>15</span>
      +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">incrementing</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>true</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">attributes</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:2</span> [<samp>
        "<span class=sf-dump-key>id</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>7</span>
        "<span class=sf-dump-key>name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="8 characters">Portland</span>"
      </samp>]
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">original</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:2</span> [<samp>
        "<span class=sf-dump-key>id</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-num>7</span>
        "<span class=sf-dump-key>name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="8 characters">Portland</span>"
      </samp>]
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">relations</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">hidden</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">visible</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">appends</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">guarded</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:1</span> [<samp>
        <span class=sf-dump-index>0</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str>*</span>"
      </samp>]
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">dates</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">dateFormat</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">casts</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">touches</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">observables</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">with</span>: []
      #<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">morphClass</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">exists</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>true</span>
      +<span class=sf-dump-public title="Public property">wasRecentlyCreated</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>false</span>
    </samp>}
  </samp>]
</samp>}
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-981673028")</script>
```

It seems like it is showing the correct areas from the attributes, but just isn't displaying them out under the area selection. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you please generate the working demo of this ? So that we can check .

Comment: @Manish thanks for trying to give me a hand. I have solved the problem :)

Comment: Thats great  !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the procedure you have to follow is the first country id you have to send then take its respective cities until location box will be disabled then send only state id and fetch locations from that and you will get the proper result.Please refer below link

http://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: Thanks for the link! It works now, but I modified a little bit to suit my needs.